# How to set line linebreak when passing parameters to Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am passing parameters to Facebook using JSON concept.I am passing Location name and Date in that. After location name i want to display Date in new line.Can any one help me how to give line break. Here is the my code.
Thanks in Advance.

```
NSString *att=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"%@\","
                   "\"href\":\"%@\","
                   "\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\","
                   "\"src\":\"%@\","
                   "\"href\":\"%@\"}],"
                   "\"properties\":{\"Location\":\"%@\"\"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Date\":\"%@\"}}",eventTitle.text,href,imageSource,imageHref,eventLocation.text,eventDate.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really a Facebook question. But certainly HTML-escaped spaces won't work.

You're probably looking for an escaped newline, \n

In fact, you'll need to escape it twice: once for NSString and once for JSON, ending up \n in your code